# What to do if you accidentally downvote something you did not want to downvote?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

User laziness at the best: I was browsing one question here on worldbuilding on my mobile device. As I scroll, I accidentally put my finger on "downvote" arrow, causing vote down on one of provided answers.

Normally, I do cast upvote instead, but in some cases I would like just to leave answer/question as it was (effective zero vote).

I know, it is just internet points, but sometimes I do this on question or answer I believe does not deserve downvote, but I think it also does not deserve upvote.

Is there mechanic to "null" my vote on question or answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By clicking on the downvote arrow again, you can undo your vote. This is the same with upvotes as well. Keep in mind that after 5 minutes this will not work without an edit, so just randomly edit (temporarily), do the deed, then re-edit back to its originalpoint

Comment: But votes are locked in after about five minutes, so if he didn't notice right away, that won't solve the problem.  (A subsequent edit unlocks votes.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio good point, editted

Comment: Why didn't I just try that? Maybe I was just thinking that it will cast double downvote ;) Thank you! (Also triple up voted this just to try the mechanism)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to randomly edit, even if you're going to rollback said edit. It creates clutter and bumps the post to the front page for no reason.

Comment: That said, I haven't seen an SE post without a spelling or grammar mistake. You can usually find something to fix if you look hard enough.